# Google Map API Style for Whitewater from Google Map Engine

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering how and where can I extract the JSON styling for the Base Map "Whitewater" from Google Map Engine?

Here is an example of such map: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=z-BEFzFo7gdM.kYdiUKVQpQQI

However, there are no solid style found in Google's API docs.

Thanks
Bill

Comment: What is  "Whitewater"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to google maps engine Pro, this is the JSON for style "Whitewater"

```
[ { "stylers" : [ { "visibility" : "on" },
        { "saturation" : -13 },
        { "lightness" : -17 },
        { "hue" : "#ff6e00" }
      ] },
  { "featureType" : "water",
    "stylers" : [ { "visibility" : "on" },
        { "lightness" : 100 }
      ]
  },
  { "featureType" : "poi",
    "stylers" : [ { "lightness" : 39 },
        { "saturation" : -43 },
        { "visibility" : "on" }
      ]
  },
  { "elementType" : "geometry",
    "featureType" : "roads",
    "stylers" : [ { "visibility" : "on" },
        { "lightness" : 30 }
      ]
  },
  { "elementType" : "labels",
    "stylers" : [ { "lightness" : 35 } ]
  }
]
```

Comment: That did it. I was surprised that Google did not have these in the API docs.